# How to make Google Cloud Function in the PDT or PST time zones

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud function that parses the day of the month from a UTC date
For example myDate = Wed Nov 13 2019 02:05:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
This date is actually Tues Nov 12 in San Francisco time (PDT or PST).

But when in my Google cloud function, when I try to get the day of the month from this date with myDate.getDate(), I get 13 instead of 12.

I believe the reason why it returns 13 is because the time zone of the machine that the cloud function is running on is based on UTC time.  When I run this function on my local machine, I get 12 as the correct date because my local machine is on PST time.

How do I make Google Cloud Function operated in the PDT or PST time zones so that the getDate() function gives me the correct date in the PDT or PST time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Doug said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58840725/634824), it's not possible to configure the timezone on a Cloud Functions server instance.

However, you don't need a library.  Google Cloud Functions using NodeJS 8 or 10 can get the date in a particular time zone using the JavaScript Internationalization API:

```
let myDate = new Date("2019-11-13T02:05:00Z");  // the value you gave in the question
let s = myDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' })
//=> "11/12/2019"
```

If you just want the numeric day of the month, you can extract it from the string from there.

```
+(s.split('/')[1])   //=> 12
```

Answer (score 9):

### 2020 Update

As of [Node 14](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/20026), which is now in [beta for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#cli_v8-19-0) as of Dec 11, 2020, you *should* be able to just do

```
process.env.TZ = 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

Comment: I tested this with my script and it worked fine +1

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to configure the timezone on a Cloud Functions server instance.

It's better if your code does not depend on the local timezone configuration at all.  If you need your date logic to format dates for a specific timezone, you should be using a library that knows how to do this, such as moment.  It has comprehensive date manipulation utilities, and there is an addon for timezones.  https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Setting your Cloud Functions to operate in PDT or PST is not achievable. This is a constant which depends on the environment they run on. On the actual machine. You can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations) a list which contains the possible locations for you to run the Cloud Functions.

If you need to obtain the Pacific time in your Cloud Function, just use this portion of code. It will give you the the PDT.

```
var offset = -8;
new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000).toUTCString().replace( / GMT$/, "" )
```