# getTimezoneOffset() in Cloud Function always returns zero

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I'm running getTimezoneOffset() in Cloud Function on Google Cloud it always returns zero.

```
console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
```

Environment: NodeJS

Location: us-east4 (Ashburn, Virginia)

On my local PC it returns correct offset.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please try the solutions proposed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832296/how-to-make-google-cloud-function-in-the-pdt-or-pst-time-zones

Comment: The function time is UTC. That means the time zone offset is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected result you are getting is correct because the function time is UTC. That means the time zone offset is 0.